# exception with java data structure

Tags: java, linked-list

I am writing a generic data structure that can add and delete from the first or last nodes
I tested my code however I got exceptions in some certain way of input.

now if I addlast then addfirst then removelast i got exception

and when I addfirst many time without adding last then try to remove them by removelast() function i got exception
but when I addlast many time without adding first then remove them by removefirst() it works

I am trying to avoid while loops here is the code

```
 import java.util.Iterator;
 public class Deque <Item> implements Iterable <Item> {

private Node first,last;

private class Node
{
    Item item;
    Node next;
    Node prev;
}

public Deque()
{
    first = null;
    last = null;
}

public boolean IsEmpty()
{
    return first == null;
}

public void addFirst(Item item)
{
    Node oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    first.prev = null;
    if (last == null)
    {
        last = first;

    }

}

public void addlast(Item item)
{
    Node oldlast = last;
    last = new Node();
    last.item = item;
    last.next = null;
    if (first == null)
    {
        first = last;
    }
    else
    {
        last.prev = oldlast;
        oldlast.next = last;
    }
}

public Item removeFirst()
{
    Item x = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    if (IsEmpty())
        last = null;
    return x;
}

public Item removeLast()
{
    if (first == last)
        return removeFirst();
    Item x = last.item;
    last = last.prev;
    last.next = null;
    if (IsEmpty())
        first = null;
    return x;
}

public Iterator<Item> iterator ()
{
    return new ListIterator();
}

private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item>
{
    private Node current = first;

    public boolean hasNext ()
    {
        return current != null;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        //NOt Supported
    }

    public Item next()
    {
        Item x = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return x;
    }
```

}
}

I believe I have something wrong with last.prev in removelast() since it is already null and then referred last = last.perv in remove()
but i couldnt think of a way to link last to last node of first

can anyone help me with this

here is the main if you want to try...

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Deque<Integer> o = new Deque<Integer>();
    int num = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        StdOut.println("enter 1 to addfirst, 2 addlast, 3 removefirst, 4 removelast, " +
                "5 to exit");
        num = StdIn.readInt();
        if (num == 5)
            break;
        switch (num)
        {
        case 1:
            StdOut.println("enter number to add first");
            int x = StdIn.readInt();
            o.addFirst(x);
            break;
        case 2:
            StdOut.println("enter number to add last");
            int y = StdIn.readInt();
            o.addlast(y);
            break;
        case 3:
            int w=o.removeFirst();
            StdOut.print("the deleted number is: ");
            StdOut.print(w);
            StdOut.println();
            break;
        case 4:
            int z=o.removeLast();
            StdOut.print("the deleted number is: ");
            StdOut.print(z);
            StdOut.println();
            break;
        default:
            StdOut.println("Stick with the range!");
            break;
        }

        for (Iterator<Integer> i=o.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
        {
            StdOut.print(i.next());
            StdOut.print("  ");
        }
        StdOut.println();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: "_i got exception_" --> Which exception (and also stacktrace)? "_I am trying to avoid while loops_" --> **Why ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a couple of operations.  In `addFirst` you don't set `oldFirst.prev = first;`, so if you add nodes with it, you won't have any `prev` references defined.  That is why removeLast fails.  It attempts to clean traverse to `last.prev`, but since everything was added with `addFirst`, `last.prev` is null.

Also, in `removeFirst`, you have a similar issue, that you don't remove the link to the former `prev` node, such as `first.prev = null;`  Without doing that, if you were traversing using `prev` references, you would be able to move beyond the first node, after having called `removeFirst`.

`addLast` and `addFirst` should do, in essence, exactly the same things, just at different ends of the list.  `addFirst` looks simpler, in your implementation, which means either you missed something in `addFirst`, or `addLast` is overly complex.  In this case, you missed something in `addFirst`.  Same with the remove methods.